# Specified cast is not valid error for ip address

Tags: c#

[image]
I'm getting the attached exception for a value of:
"211.26.133.198           "

Anyone know why?

Comment: is there a .ToString() method specified for ((object[])(row))[14]? Is yes, try to use it - it may work more proper, then (string) convertion.

Comment: @cookieMonster thanks, I tried that, I get the exact same error

Comment: ok, how about assigning ((object[])(row))[14] to an object variable, and then try to convert it to something (may sound silly, but who knows).

Comment: @cookieMonster I did try that..... Even "var ipNo = ((object[])(row))[14];" fails with the same error seems like a bug of some sort...

Comment: Probably makes no difference but I usually write (string)(((object[])row)[14])

Comment: hm, can we look at the mapping for this column? (and did you try closing vs and opening it up again or even restarting your system - i remember i spent whole night trying to deal with some bug and the thing was in vs itself)

Comment: @iKode I would also verify that the characters after the actual IP value are spaces and no control characters.

Comment: @Steve Mallory, how can I do that? It seems like it needs to be a string for me to manipulate it in any way?

Comment: @cookieMonster there is no mapping I'm using SQL

Comment: @iKode I would try copying and pasting into a decent text editor, such as Scite.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly why it is happening (Nothing looks obviously incorrect)...

Try Convert.ToString instead of the cast and see what happens :)

Comment: Can you try Convert.ToString() as deadlyDev pointed out, there doesnt seem something really obvious from your code that points to that error...

Comment: Also, just to be sure, there is a lot going on in that one line...can you try adding just ((object[])(row))[14] into the watch list and examining it's underlying type?

Comment: @AshesToAshes I tried what deadlyDev suggested and get the same error. You can see the watch of that value in the original screen shot...

Comment: OK try what I mentioned in the Watch list - it's similar to what cookieMonster  is saying...

Comment: @AshesToAshes it works in the watch but continues to fail when I try to do it in the code

Comment: The only further advice I can give you is to try split that line into its component parts and try to see exactly which piece is causing the cast exception... This does look kinda strange though...

Just to clarify:

object[] rowData = (object[])row;
object rowValue = rowData[14];
string ipNo = (string)rowValue;